# How can I optimize swapping elements of the array in c++

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

my task is to code the enigma machine. I' ve nearly done it but the only thing that slows me is the fact that whole code in every case must execute in less than 3 seconds. There are thousands of variables, arrays like [1000+] so I need to optimize my code. First thing I would like to change is my swapping function. I heard about something like circullar array but I'm not sure how it works. Generally the point is before every coding I need to rotate the rotor once. If there are numbers higher than thousands it might take a lot of time I think, any ideas for that?
Firstly I have a class that storage only used rotors as I can declare them any number but I declare before every coding how much of them and then I set their position like
normal alphabet 1 2 3 4, rotor set for 1 2 4 3 and every number coding rotor rotates to 2 4 3 1 then 4 3 1 2 then 3 1 2 4 etc... and the same in the reverse.

```
for(int i=0;i<ile_rotorow_wiad;i++)
        {
            rotory_uzyte[i].copy(rotory[wiadomosc.jakie_rotory[i]],ile_liter, rotory_rev[wiadomosc.jakie_rotory[i]]);
            rotory_uzyte[i].Obroc(wiadomosc.pozycja[i], ile_liter);
        }
```

that's the code that is running every loop while the "enigma message" isn't equal 0.

```
rotory_uzyte[0].Obroc(2, ile_liter);
```

function Obroc:

```
void Rotor::Obroc(int pozycja, int ile)
{     
    for(int i=0;i<pozycja-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<ile-1;j++)
        {
            swap(pozycje[j],pozycje[j+1]);
            swap(pozycje_rev[j],pozycje_rev[j+1]);
        }  
    }

}
```

As you can see for high numbers it is useless and would take so much time. Any ideas how to optimize it if it makes "rounds" like circles I can't name it. As I mentioned a circular array would be a good thing? How should it look like then?

Comment: Hi that's interesting, not sure if this might be of use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

Comment: I’m not familiar with the engima machine but, in general, moving blocks of memory around that have been allocated dynamically is going to be a very expensive thing to do. If you can think of a way to index into your array using an offset and modulo arithmetic, you should see large performance gains

Comment: The net effect of the inner loop is popping the first `pozycja-1` elements from the beginning of the two arrays (containers?), shuffling the rest left, , and then inserting the popped elements at the end.   That could probably be optimised with a temporary container, and a couple of calls of `std::copy()` for each array.   How well that well optimise - that depends on what the elements are, and how copying them works, which you have not specified.

Comment: Assuming you have six rotors/arrays: instead of copying 6 arrays, why don't you just cache an index to each array. This index represents the current array element. Then you only need to increment the index, rather than move memory around?